# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on method in class

Tags: objective-c, exc-bad-access, ios10

I have the following methods in my `SQLiteManager.m` implementation. Warning: old legacy code alert

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    if (db != nil) {
        [self closeDatabase];
    }
    [databaseName release];
}

- (NSError *) closeDatabase 
{    
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (db != nil) {
            // Set and log error somewhere, not relevant here
        }
        db = nil;
    }
    return error;
}
```

When I run my app in debug mode on iOS 10 iPad, it runs fine. When I run my app in release mode on iOS 10 iPad (with development certificate and provisioning profile), the app crashes on the line `[self closeDatabase];`, returning a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. I see in my console that `self` still is an SQLiteManager object. How is it possible that a reference to a method in your own class can give rise to a bad access error, and only in release mode?

PS: When I run with `NSZombieEnabled = YES`, the app runs fine.

Comment: Does a stack trace of the crashing thread show anything?  (i.e. Type 'bt' at the (lldb) prompt.)

Comment: Sounds like your SQLiteManager object became a zombie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer. I had to place the call `[super dealloc];` to the end of the overridden `dealloc` method.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    if (db != nil) {
        [self closeDatabase];
    }
    [databaseName release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```